# Node + Mongo: Chained driver methods are executed asynchronously?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Feel a bit sheepish asking something so remedial given I've been using Node & Mongo for a year now. That whole time I've stuck to the form;

```
collection.find({field:value}, function(error, cursor) {
    if (error) return ErrorHandler(error);
    cursor.toArray(function(error, results) {
        if (error) return ErrorHandler(error);
        ...
    });
});
```

Mainly because (back when I was first trying to get my head around Node's single-threaded ways) each database call is explicitly non-blocking. But obviously it's a bit verbose compared to;

```
collection.find({field:value}).toArray(function(error, results) {
    if (error) return ErrorHandler(error);
    ...
});
```

I wonder if someone could just confirm for me that the second form is equivalently asynchronous and that the driver is dealing with the find callback in the background and only calling me back when both things are done?

Is there reason to suppose the second form might be a bit more performant (on the basis that the driver is presumably implemented in a low-level language)?